# static/compile time check for javascript with jquery?

Tags: javascript, syntax-checking

I know javascript (or at least a version of it) can be compiled into .NET provided certain conditions are met. How can i do a compile time or static syntax check on javascript i am writing? The catch is, it must support jquery

Cause someone will ask, to compile (with ms .net) is

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\jsc thefile.js
```

writing package thenamespace { class ClassName{ around where necessary. Then you can add this as a normal reference. From experience the references are not always compatible with mono.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are any static analyzers which can check the validity of jQuery code in depth, but for the Javascript syntax itself, there are non-web versions of [Javascript Lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/) and [JSLint](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint) you could use.

If you're using Visual Studio, you could also give [JSLint.VS](http://jslint.codeplex.com/) a try for better integration.

**UPDATE**: Since I wrote this, [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) and [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) have taken over as the most popular members of the JSLint family.

Also, [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) is gaining popularity. It's a superset of JavaScript with optional static types which compiles to plain JavaScript. (For those who have used [MyPy](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/) for Python, it's similar. Valid JavaScript is [also valid TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html), but you can incrementally add type annotations and the compiler will use them to catch bugs.)

Comment: AFAIK all lints just check syntax and occasional bad or good practice. Does any of these keep the type in mind ?

Comment: I've never run across a static analyzer which could make any kind of reliable attempt at managing types in an implicitly-typed, dynamically-typed language like Javascript. (Or Python, for that matter, which I also use.)